# SELECT UPDATE ALL ROWS AT THE SAME TIME MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update and select the same table as the following:

```
UPDATE tbl_domain SET remain = 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(expdate,NOW()) FROM (
SELECT DATEDIFF(expdate,NOW()) FROM tbl_domain 
) as x )
```

How can i make it work ? Someone please help me!!!

Comment: Do you mean selecting the new results after you update them?

Comment: No. I just wanna update all the rows daily.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Error says: Subquery returns more than 1 rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_domain t, (SELECT DATEDIFF(expdate,NOW()) as remain
                        FROM tbl_domain 
                       ) t1
SET t.remain = t1.remain
-- WHERE t.Id = t1.Id --If you have some kind of unique id in your table.
```

Comment: There's a warning: 'Data truncated for column 'remain' at row 1'

Comment: This means your column 'remain', can not store the updated values. You can check your column data type or format the datediff part.